# I get "fatal: unable to create threaded lstat" error when I run "git status" command

Tags: linux, git, ssh

Hi StackOverflow Team!

Recently I got strange responses from git I use on my SiteGround hosting. When I run the `git status` command in my repository I get the following error:

```
serv01.ams38.siteground.eu [~/www/cledu (cart-editor)] git status
fatal: unable to create threaded lstat
serv01.ams38.siteground.eu [~/www/cledu (cart-editor)]
```

On the net I found few people having similar issues and I tried these commands:

```
git config --global pack.windowMemory "100m"
git config --global pack.packSizeLimit "100m"
git config --global pack.threads "1"
git config --global pack.deltaCacheSize "512MiB"
```

But it didn't solve the issue.

Can you help me to solve this?

Best, 
Chris.

Comment: Got the same issue just today and I'm on Siteground as well. Yesterday, everything works just fine. I also tried the git config commands above but it doesn't work. Right now, I contacted the support at siteground to see if they can help me with it. Maybe they changed something in the server. I can't commit, I can only pull.

Comment: The guys at Siteground recently replied to my ticket and they said that they are working to fix the issue. I think once mine was fixed, yours will be fixed as well, as we are using the same hosting company and encountered this problem almost simultaneously.

Comment: The siteground support was able to fix my issue. I suggest that you should file a ticket as well. I can now commit, push, check my git status, etc. 

Siteground Support: "We are glad to inform you that the issue is resolved. To resolve the issue we have adjusted the server configuration and after that we were able to commit the changes:"

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If the resource limit can't be removed by the hosting provider, you could consider using git config to disable preloading of the index (threaded lstat).

```
git config core.preloadIndex false
```

If you need that setting when cloning the initial repository, then you will need to set it globally.

```
git config --global core.preloadIndex false
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! whew! :D I thought it's the end of the world already. haha :D

Comment: This worked for me in HostGator hosting

Answer (score 2):

Increasing the virtual memory limit may help. We have fixed several such cases by increasing **ulimit -v** to 1048576 (1024M). This is an arbitrary value, which I believe is not unreasonably high and yet enough.

Comment: Thank you for that. I sent the command to SiteGround support ticket (as I don't have privileges to run it). Waiting for their answer...

Comment: Chris, couple of weeks ago we increased the virtual memory limit for users on all of our servers to 1GB and you should not face this issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is [this line](https://github.com/git/git/blob/77bd3ea9f54f1584147b594abc04c26ca516d987/preload-index.c#L96) in git. The pthread_create call failed, perhaps due to some resource limit on the number of threads allowed by the user on the server side.

Comment: is there any way I can step over it and make git working again?

Comment: You should check the git/server logs for more details to detect the real cause.

Comment: I found error log there but without any recent entries.

Comment: Have you checked the kernel log? usually there you will be able to find the cause.

Comment: found error_log filein the root folder but there are just a few php4 related errors. Folder /var/log is not accessible. Looks like SiteGround is not allowing me to access them.

Comment: You should contact them, since this sounds like a system limit that they applied for your service.

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting provider is using cPanel, have them disable Shell Fork Bomb Protection via WHM. Log out, log back in.

Limits are then as per `limits.conf` / `90-nproc.conf`.

With Shell Fork Bomb Protection enabled, nproc soft limit is 35 regardless of what you set in the above conf files.