Gitlab CI - Docker with image of Debian 12 using Git 2.39.2 - can't make git commands
While using gitlab-ci and preparing build image for production, there is a problem with Git commands:
In case of git submodule update --init I'm receiving
HEAD is now at * Merge branch '*' into *
fatal: unable to create threaded lstat: Operation not permitted
fatal: Unable to checkout '*' in submodule path '*'

and composer brings :
Executing command (/builds/dev/*): 'git' 'branch' '-a' '--no-color' '--no-abbrev' '-v'
In Process.php line 356:
                                                          
  [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]  
  Unable to launch a new process.                        

Already tried this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33805069/2685996 - not helping

Did you replace output with * to redact information or is this the actual output?

Yes. there are just pathes from infrastructure

And, permissions on this folder have been given in script previously
